# Remove list from the recursive function if it is empty

Tags: c#, json, treeview

Here is a sample code from C#(.cs)

```
private List<Menu> GetMenuTree(List<Menu> list, int? idparent)
{
    return list.Where(x => x.IDParent == idparent).Select(x => new Menu()
    {
        ID = x.ID,
        IDParent = x.IDParent,
        text = x.text,
        List = GetMenuTree(list, x.ID)
    }).ToList();
}
```

In the most child of the node it gives me (>) because the List is empty.

[image]

Here is the result JSON

```
{"ID":1,"IDParent":null,"text":"Furniture",
      "List":
           [{"ID":2,"IDParent":1,"text":"Table","List":[]},
            {"ID":3,"IDParent":1,"text":"Chairs","List":[]}]
}
```

Where List[] is empty.
How to remove this if its in the most child of the node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add another function that determines if there are children or not:

```
private List<Menu> GetMenuTree(List<Menu> list, int? idparent)
{
    return list.Where(x => x.IDParent == idparent).Select(x => new Menu()
    {
        ID = x.ID,
        IDParent = x.IDParent,
        text= x.text,
        List = HasChildren(list, x.ID) ? GetMenuTree(list, x.ID) : null
    }).ToList();
}

public bool HasChildren(List<Menu> list, int? idparent)
{
    return list.Where(x => x.IDParent == idparent).FirstOrDefault() != null;
}
```

Or you could "in-line" that in the `GetMenuTree` function, but I think the readability this way is better.

Comment: Omg! Thanks! I just found an answer. Upvoting it now. Cheers!